# How to open and display incoming mails in outlook using VB? (Not VBA)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, outlook-2007

I've been struggling recently with a simple Windows Form Application that helps me automate common outlook tasks.
I know that triggering a "Display" event everytime a new email arrives is quite simple, but I'm still a noob when it comes to Visual Basic.
I must mention that all the information I've found so far deals only with VBA code and it seems that statements differ between VBA and VB.
Any ideas, suggestions or recommendations of useful websites to look at will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: VBA is used for macros within Outlook, and is your best option for something running within Outlook. You can write .NET code for Outlook, but then you need visual studio and something called VSTO. If you are doing EXCHANGE programming, then there are web services available to consume, but I don't think you want that route, especially as a newbie. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770082/vba-vs-vsto-what-is-the-difference-should-i-upgrade for some additional considerations of VBA versus .NET

Comment: also check out http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=43 if you haven't already.

Comment: Wow, those links were very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Concepts (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868025(v=office.15).aspx) section provides a lot of HowTo pages with VB.NET samples.

> I've been struggling recently with a simple Windows Form Application

It looks like you are trying to automate Outlook. In that case you may find the [How to automate Outlook by using Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595) article helpful.

As an alternative way, you may consider developing an Outlook add-in. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to get started quickly. See also the [Outlook Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386094.aspx) section in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, I found those links really useful.